# Android: How to change the navigation bar colour under Lollipop

Tags: android

While I can find a lot of tips of how to change the navigation bar colour above API level 21, there doesn't seem to be any suggestions for the same solution under Lollipop. Is there a way I can change its colour either programmatically or using style.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Use this on your Activity

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
}
```

Next code i gonna show only work on API versions above of 21.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

I think it can only be changed by the Android versions with material design where that appear.
More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) to.

Comment: I already know how to implement it above 21. I am looking for a way to do the same thing under 21.

Comment: I think you cannot do because it only appear above of 21 with Material Design like you can see here https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

And sorry i understandid wrong.